# Windows Phone 8.1 Emulator - System requirements

Tags: windows, visual-studio, windows-phone, windows-phone-emulator

I want to install the Windows Phone 8.1 Emulator, but it doens't work because of the system requirements.
But I have a brand new laptop with Windows 8.1 Pro, 64 Bit, 8GB RAM and I have active Hyper-V + Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows Update 3.

So I don't know what to do.
Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

You need to turn on Second Level Address Translation in your bios. Some laptop manufactures do not ship with this turned on.  You processor must be an i3 i5 i7 from intel.

or

Rapid Virtualization Indexing Required is required if running an AMD processor